# Delete the tag <a> and its attribute when click the button using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a button , when I click the button the it will create the link to my image. This is my code :

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
var $a = $('<a/>').attr('href', 'blahblah.com').addClass('contact');
$('#img1').wrap($a);
});
```

The problem : The link will create more and more while I click the button.
Question : How can I create only a link, although I click the button many times.

I hope you kindly to share idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the .one() function in jQuery to enable the handler only for a one time action (see http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$("#btn").one('click', function () {
    var $a = $('<a/>').attr('href', 'blahblah.com').addClass('contact');
    $('#img1').wrap($a);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
  if ($('#img1').parent('a.contact')) {
    return;
  }
  var $a = $('<a/>').attr('href', 'blahblah.com').addClass('contact');
  $('#img1').wrap($a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter variable, which should be null at first. When you click the button for first time then counter will increase. After that you can check the counter value. If that is equals to one, then you can use `stopPropagation()` method of jquery to stop that event.

Or you can use the `preventDefault()` method of jquery to stop the default event.

Else you can use the `stopImmediatePropagation()` method of jquery  to stop the current event immediately.